# Packer ansible lacking sudo permissions

Tags: ansible, packer

Trying to run a packer build with ansible playbooks, but failing to even start with the most simple task.

I have this as a packer configuration in the provisioners section:

```
"provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "playbook_file": "../ansible/main.yml",
      "ansible_env_vars": [ "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False", "ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s'", "ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=True","become=true","become_method=sudo" ]
    }
  ]
```

And this is the actual playbook content:

```
- user:
    name: foo
    comment: "Foo Bar"
```

Upon execution, this fails for the following reason:

> amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "useradd: Permission denied.\nuseradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.\n", "name": "foo", "rc": 1}

As far as I understand, this is because ansible is not running with sudo priviledges on the packer build. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html) `ansible_env_vars` is only for environment variables, but `become` and `become_method` are internal Ansible variables.

Either use extra args in provisioner config:

```
"extra_arguments": [ "--become" ]
```

Or add `become` into your playbook.